# How can I bypass Internet restrictions?

Tags: internet, encryption, restrictions, user-agent

I can only use browsers with specific user agents and [Yahoo Messenger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Messenger). I used [Fiddler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiddler_%28software%29) to change some things, but I only got browsers working by changing the user agent, everything else is blocked.

How do I bypass whatever restrictions are in place?

I also can't connect to proxy servers (and probably any kind of server).

I thought that maybe there's an application that can encrypt all traffic data and send it (like a browser - no other way works) to a server, have the server decrypt it and send the response encrypted. I don't know how to search for such an application, it's too specific. Can this be achieved?

Comment: What restrictions are you talking about?

Comment: I'm not sure. I guess traffic is filtered when it goes out and certain data is blocked. I couldn't tell you what kind of data can go through and what is blocked though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Openvpn-ALS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openvpn-als/) is a [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) server that runs over SSL on port 443, using Java on the client side in a browser session.

This means that you can connect and establish a VPN provided port 443 is permitted, either directly or via a proxy, and your machine supports Java. All within a browser, so it should come under your user-agent.

Once established, you can direct all or some of your traffic across the VPN. How successful this will work in your environment is not knowable given the limited details you have provided.